# Simple way to get number of rows in result set or ADO recordset

Tags: c#, sql, .net-3.5

My execute sql task returns a "full result set" which I store in an Object objResults. I want a simple way to get the number of rows in objResults. How do I do it ? I want to use c# code to get that number.

I could load the whole objResults into a DataTable and get the numberOfRows with `myDataTable.Rows.Count;`, but that approach is obviously inefficient.

NOTE - I am using .NET 3.5 and visual studio 2008. I know there is a 4.0/visual studio method for this. But it won't work for me.

Here is the solution for 4.0 -

The object is actually an ADO recordset.  It's a COM object so to use it from C# you either need the interop assembly or dynamic.  dynamic is easier.

In your Script Task add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp and then access the recordset like this:

```
public void Main()
{
  dynamic result = Dts.Variables["result"].Value;
  int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(result.RecordCount);

  Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

You can also add a row count column to a SQL query by adding a colulmn with the expression `COUNT(*) over ()`, eg:

```
select *, count(*) over () row_count
from whatever
```

Thanks to - 
David
[David http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/)

Comment: Hi ! I will putting a bounty on this one. Please visit this question 2 days later if you are interested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" Library. Then you will have the COM interop type definitions to work with ADO in C#.

Use the C# script:

```
public void Main()
{
    ADODB.Recordset result = (ADODB.Recordset) Dts.Variables["result"].Value;
    int rowCount = result.RecordCount;

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

How to add a reference -

Edit the script and add a reference (menu project) Steps here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308611/en-us. 
**Then, don't forget to save afterwards. Click Save All to save adding the reference!**

ctrl + s will only save your codes. To do save all, use ctrl+shift+s. LOL ! So unintuitive !