# C++ - Access field in recordset

Tags: c++, ms-access

I am trying to access the field values of recordset. Currently there is a loop to count the recordsets but I don't know how to access specific fields.

```
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)L"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\Temp\\Data.accdb;", SQL_NTS,szConnStrOut, 255, &iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
{
    rc2 = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
    rc2 = SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT UniqueID FROM ObjectCheck", SQL_NTS);

    /* Execute the query and create a record set */
    rc2 = SQLExecute(hStmt);

    /* Loop through the rows in the result set */
    rc2 = SQLFetch(hStmt);

    while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc2))
    {
        rc2 = SQLFetch(hStmt);
        rowCount++;         
        //cout << UniqueID;
        //rc3 = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
        //rc3 = SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT * FROM DependsOn WHERE UniqueID = " , SQL_NTS);
    };

    cout << rowCount;
}
```

Best regards
Steve

Comment: Presume you mean to 'count records' not 'recordsets'. Instead of looping to count records, can you not just reference the RecordCount property of recordset? Can you adapt C# code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713039/simple-way-to-get-number-of-rows-in-result-set-or-ado-recordset

Comment: Otherwise, review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-us/f64e720e-64ad-47ea-867f-db082e774afb/retrieving-a-recordset-from-a-stored-procedure-in-c-using-ado